# Django : Cancel a change in the database

Tags: database, django

I'm looking for a way to cancel a change in the database.
Indeed, I'm uploading files and saving data into the database. But I want for the user to have the possibility to cancel this upload. That is to say, to retrieve the file and the instance created thanks to this file.

I don't know if you can just delete the models you want to delete, the primary keys, the ids...

If you have any idea about the best way to do it ?
Thank you

The user must be able to click on a cancel link. This link must undo the actions he did just before : he uploaded a file on the file system. Some data and models were generated thanks to this file.

```
class FunctionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    function_name = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=FUNCTIONS) 

    class Meta :
        model = Function
        exclude =('session_number')



# File form : used in Creation function
class FileForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta :
        model = File
        exclude = ('function','file_name','version')

class File(models.Model):

    # Attributs
    filea  = models.FileField(upload_to ='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/')
    file_name = models.CharField("File name ", max_length=50)
    creation_date = models.DateField("Upload date ",auto_now=True)
    version = models.IntegerField("Version ")  
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file_name +" "+ str(self.version) +" "+ str(self.creation_date)
```

Comment: Please provide your models and some more details on the use case, it is very hard to guess what you really want

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a model that refers to all of the other models created by the action, and use that to delete them (and itself).